# GAS, MOVQ Throws operand mismatch, when trying to copy rax to mmx register

Tags: assembly, gnu, mmx

I'm using gnu assembly and gcc compiler.
I have to make some operations using mmx registers.
I've got a memory buffer of bytes, I'm reading 1 byte from memory to %al, making logical and operation and shifting rax left by 1 byte and inserting on lower bits next byte from memory until %rax gets full. Then when I'm trying to do:

```
movq %rax, %mm0
```

compilers throws: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'

Examples:

This works:

```
   mov $0, %rcx\n"
   movl , %ecx\n"
   mov (%1, %rcx, 8), %rbx\n"
   movq %rbx, %mm0
```

This don't:

```
mov (variable_that_contains_address, %rcx, 4), %rax ;get 4 bits from memory
movb %al, %bl 
andb $0b00011111, %bl ;only lower 5 bits needed
movb %bl, %dl ;store whole byte at rdx
shl $8, %rdx  ;make space for next byte
shr $5, %rax  ; I need next 5 bits, because data in memory are saved not in bytes 
movb %al, %bl ;next 5 bits  
;repating until rdx is full (some higher bits unused)

movq %rdx, %mm0 ; and now compiler throws mismatch error
```

This code is not full code - full code is very long. It's made for your intuition.

Why it hates me so much? What I'm doing wrong. 
Please don't complain about methodology of getting those 5 bits, I need help only with storing rdx into mm0.

Answer (score 0):

```
movq %rbx, %mm0
```

Give `movd` a go?

Don't forget that if you only need 5 bits you can use the carry flag with 1 byte

```
shr $5, %rax 10111
```

will set the carry

```
shr $5, %rax  01110
```

will not

Comment: how to use this flag in the way you meant?

Comment: thank you, that's a good option. I've tried movd, tried pushing to stack. still mismatches...